# Match JSON arrays with JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I have JSON from REST API:

```json
{
  "fields": [
    "advertiser_id",
    "campaign_id",
    "day"
  ],
  "data": [
    [
      "8905",
      "234870",
      "2021-09-28"
    ],
    [
      "5634",
      "88467870",
      "2021-09-28"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I want to match values inside `fields` array with values inside `data`. The have same order. So I expect to get:

```json
[
  {
    "advertiser_id": "8905",
    "campaign_id": "234870",
    "day": "2021-09-28"
  },
  {
    "advertiser_id": "5634",
    "campaign_id": "88467870",
    "day": "2021-09-28"
  }
]
```

Any ways to do it with JOLT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a shift transformation spec in which

- go 4 levels up (traverse once`:`, and `{` triple) in order to reach
  fields array as picking sub-arrays of `data` array by using `[&1]`
- dissipate all returning key-value pairs through use of `[&2].` node

such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&2].@(4,fields[&1])"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]